# how to remove unwanted � character from webpage developed in php

Tags: php, html

I have a `.php` page where am getting � character...can you please help me to remove this character from the page?

The code for line where am getting this character is here

```
<td class='forcedWidth'><?php echo "<a href=".$row->TW_URL.">".$row->EAN."</a>"; ?></td>
```

I am completely clueless about this character.

Comment: This character is due to bad encoding. You should figure out where this character is coming from (database, included file, etc) and remove it or convert it to the proper encoding of your site.

Comment: As well as it possibly being from the database, you can define which charset to use in PHP headers and in HTML meta. There is possibly a mismatch. We need to see some code.

Comment: It can be helpful if you provide the code which gives ?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through, this might enlighten you..

Answer (score 5):

Put this in the head section

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

if that doesn't do it use the [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) command

```
echo(utf8_decode($text));
```

Comment: while changing the code to echo(utf8_decode($text)); its giving me ? instead of that character

Comment: @JoyeetaSinharay That's because the data was inserted in the database in the wrong way, check my comment above..